# JQuery fullscreen background does not work after vertical aligning a div

Tags: html, css

I used JQuery fullscreen plugin ( http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/ ), And some CSS techniques for vertical aligning a `<div>` everything works in FF/Chrome but none of IE browsers shows it correctly. it's the website: http://negar.in

Comment: What were your CSS techniques for v-align? If they're not working in IE, then they're probably not designed with IE's broken CSS implementation in mind.

Comment: they are working, div in vertically aligned, but background is misplaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using table instead of div for vertical alignment.